# Can't access scrollcontroller in Listview under SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I'm unable to access the `scrollContoller` in the `ListView.builder`. I think its because it's below `SingleChildScrollView` (when I remove `SingleChildScrollView` I start getting print statements from the listener attached to the `scrollController` ). I need to access the `offset` from scrollController in the `ListView.builder` but not sure how to do so. Here's a minimum example. How would I get the listener printing from the controller in the listView..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(() {
      print("Why am I not getting print statements....");
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollController,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 30,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length].withOpacity(0.5),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}
```

Comment: *"I think its because it's below SingleChildScrollView"* - yes, you have to remove `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: That's not an option for me. The example is a minimum example I need the `SingleChildScrollView` because  I need my whole screen to scroll. Wondering what my options are... @pskink

Comment: `CustomScrollView` with some `slivers:`

Comment: thanks, trying to avoid slivers if possible. Just wondering is there another way to go. I've seen this package from google and wonder would this do the trick? linked_scroll_controller: ^0.2.0

Comment: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cc9b78fc5c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart#L1178, this is how `ListView.builder` builds slivers under the hood - so ordinary `ListView` uses slivers as well

Comment: ah ok.. I'll have a play around with it. But from what I understand a ordinary `Listview` can be used with a`CustomScrollView`

Comment: *"[...] a ordinary Listview can be used with a CustomScrollView"* - read [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) official docs - they explain how to use it